# django facebook connect missing libs?

Tags: python, django, facebook, integration, fbconnect

I'm trying to integrate some photo related functionality with my site and facebook. I checked out facebook connect and it seems like the way to go for this (since I don't want to make an app, just have users authenticate and then grab some content from facebook to integrate into our site)

First of all, if you think there is a better way to do this (infinite session maybe?) let me know.

Otherwise here is the problem I'm having... I downloaded [django-fbconnect](http://code.google.com/p/django-fbconnect/) and installed it as an app (as per the readme.txt included in the svn) but python is complaining about a missing signals.py

```
Error: No module named signals
```

which I assume should be fbconnect/signals.py because of this line of code:

```
from fbconnect.signals import facebook_update
```

Anyway does anyone have experience with django-fbconnect? or any advice on getting the developer to update google code?

Thanks

**edit**: Found this: "[Integrating Facebook Connect with Django in 15 minutes](http://nyquistrate.com/django/facebook-connect/)" which uses middleware instead of the django-fbconnect app. I prefer the app because it's lighter and the code is clearer. Also, it sticks to the 'everything is an app' culture of django. but I guess I'll look into this other possibility

**edit 2**: I contacted the original author of django-fbconnect, and he graciously updated the project with the missing file (he also answered on this post)

Comment: Jim, it appears that you found issue #1 in the project issue tracker and added your comment.  The bug was created on Nov. 18 with r4 so I'd say this project is pretty much dead.  It might be possible to fork the project and try to create a new signals.py.

Comment: Actually, I just realized something after looking at the project wiki.  The signal stuff is only there to update your local user profile information if it is changed on Facebook.  If you don't need that functionality, just comment out the call to signal in profile.py.

Comment: You *can* clean the MiddleWare right down. He's using it to only allow his friends to create accounts on the site. You can also swap the logic around to use guard clauses. My version is under 150 lines (and only 5 indents at the most indented part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added the missing file folks. Sorry for the inconveniences. :/

Answer (score 0):

the solution proposeed by van gale (removing the lines which reference the signals.py file) work well enough. I think I may end up needing to write my own signals.py eventually... I keep you updated.

Anyway here's is the answer:

**<s>Remove the functionality and all uses of it, provided by the signals.py</s>**

<s>it's kind of crappy, but oh well</s>

The missing file has been added to the google code project! :)